# Jsoup :contains(string) correct usage?

Tags: javascript, jsoup, string-formatting

I am very new to java and jsoup and cant figure one simple thing out, hope you guys can help.

This works:

```
Element data = doc.select("tr:contains(Findme)").first();
```

But how can i use string instead of static text?
This wont work:

```
String IneedToFindThis = "Findme";
Element data = doc.select("tr:contains(IneedToFindThis)").first();
```

Comment: this is purely a matter of string formatting/concatenation, totally unrelated to Jsoup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String text = "findme";
Element data = doc.select(String.format("tr:contains(%s)", text)).first();
```